# Performance of std::function compared to raw function pointer and void* this?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-function, std-function

Library code:

```
class Resource 
{
public:
    typedef void (*func_sig)(int, char, double, void*);
//Registration
    registerCallback(void* app_obj, func_sig func)
    {
        _app_obj = app_obj;
        _func = func;
    }

//Calling when the time comes
    void call_app_code()
    {
        _func(231,'a',432.4234,app_obj);
    }
//Other useful methods
private:
    void* app_obj;
    func_sig _func;
//Other members
};
```

Application Code:

```
class App
{
public:
    void callme(int, char, double);
//other functions, members;
};

void callHelper(int i, char c, double d, void* app_obj)
{
    static_cast<App*>(app_obj)->callme(i,c,d);
}

int main()
{
    App a;
    Resource r;
    r.registercallback(&a, callHelper);
//Do something
}
```

The above is a minimal implementation of callback mechanism. It is more verbose, doesn't support binding, placeholders etc., like std::function.
If I use a `std::function` or `boost::function` for the above usecase, will there be any performance drawbacks? This callback is going to be in the very very critical path of a real time application. I heard that boost::function uses virtual functions to do the actual dispatch. Will that be optimized out if there are no binding/placeholders involved?

**Update**

For those interested in inspecting the assemblies in latest compilers: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/-6mQvt

Comment: Why not try it and do some benchmarking?

Comment: how std::function implements the type erasure is implementation-dependent I believe (and I think Microsoft's uses virtual functions), so the answer might even depend on what platform you are targetting. if i were you i would try some benchmarks

Comment: I agree that benchmarking would show. I am wondering if it is theoretically possible for std::function to specialise such cases and be as efficient as plain function ptr.

Comment: @balki: Like "SSO" for std::string there is a possibility of SFO (small functor optimization) for std::function. This will avoid the dynamic memory allocation and speed up copying std::function objects. If you care about the invocation overhead you should not be using std::function or function pointers but try to use the functors directly. This will enable inlining. Anyhow, test it. You might also want to check whether your C++ vendor does SFO for std::function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wondered myself quite frequently already, so I started writing some very minimal benchmark that attempts to simulate the performance by looped atomic counters for each function-pointer callback version.

Keep in mind, these are *bare* calls to functions that do only one thing, atomically incrementing its counter;

By checking the generated assembler output you may find out, that a bare C-function pointer loop is compiled into 3 CPU instructions;

a C++11's `std::function` call just adds 2 more CPU instructions, thus 5 in our example. As a conclusion: it absolutely doesn't matter what way of function pointer technique you use, the overhead differences are in any case very small.

((Confusing however is that the assigned lambda expression seems to run faster than the others, even than the C-one.))

Compile the example with: `clang++ -o tests/perftest-fncb tests/perftest-fncb.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread -lpthread -lrt -O3 -march=native -mtune=native`

```
#include <functional>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef unsigned long long counter_t;

struct Counter {
    volatile counter_t bare;
    volatile counter_t cxx;
    volatile counter_t cxo1;
    volatile counter_t virt;
    volatile counter_t lambda;

    Counter() : bare(0), cxx(0), cxo1(0), virt(0), lambda(0) {}
} counter;

void bare(Counter* counter) { __sync_fetch_and_add(&counter->bare, 1); }
void cxx(Counter* counter) { __sync_fetch_and_add(&counter->cxx, 1); }

struct CXO1 {
    void cxo1(Counter* counter) { __sync_fetch_and_add(&counter->cxo1, 1); }
    virtual void virt(Counter* counter) { __sync_fetch_and_add(&counter->virt, 1); }
} cxo1;

void (*bare_cb)(Counter*) = nullptr;
std::function<void(Counter*)> cxx_cb;
std::function<void(Counter*)> cxo1_cb;
std::function<void(Counter*)> virt_cb;
std::function<void(Counter*)> lambda_cb;

void* bare_main(void* p) { while (true) { bare_cb(&counter); } }
void* cxx_main(void* p) { while (true) { cxx_cb(&counter); } }
void* cxo1_main(void* p) { while (true) { cxo1_cb(&counter); } }
void* virt_main(void* p) { while (true) { virt_cb(&counter); } }
void* lambda_main(void* p) { while (true) { lambda_cb(&counter); } }

int main()
{
    pthread_t bare_thread;
    pthread_t cxx_thread;
    pthread_t cxo1_thread;
    pthread_t virt_thread;
    pthread_t lambda_thread;

    bare_cb = &bare;
    cxx_cb = std::bind(&cxx, std::placeholders::_1);
    cxo1_cb = std::bind(&CXO1::cxo1, &cxo1, std::placeholders::_1);
    virt_cb = std::bind(&CXO1::virt, &cxo1, std::placeholders::_1);
    lambda_cb = [](Counter* counter) { __sync_fetch_and_add(&counter->lambda, 1); };

    pthread_create(&bare_thread, nullptr, &bare_main, nullptr);
    pthread_create(&cxx_thread, nullptr, &cxx_main, nullptr);
    pthread_create(&cxo1_thread, nullptr, &cxo1_main, nullptr);
    pthread_create(&virt_thread, nullptr, &virt_main, nullptr);
    pthread_create(&lambda_thread, nullptr, &lambda_main, nullptr);

    for (unsigned long long n = 1; true; ++n) {
        sleep(1);
        Counter c = counter;

        printf(
            "%15llu bare function pointer\n"
            "%15llu C++11 function object to bare function\n"
            "%15llu C++11 function object to object method\n"
            "%15llu C++11 function object to object method (virtual)\n"
            "%15llu C++11 function object to lambda expression %30llu-th second.\n\n",
            c.bare, c.cxx, c.cxo1, c.virt, c.lambda, n
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: um, if you are using c++11, why in god's name are you using volatile?

Comment: Would the results be different if your member functions were const?

Comment: Tim Seguine, I want the compiler to not cache variables in registers on use as they're used from the worker threads AND the main thread (which periodically accesses those variables to print the stats). if I'd use std::atomic<> then the use of the volatile keyword would have been unnecessary.

Comment: masaers, No - but it is indeed a good coding paradigm to make const when it doesn't modify your local object. Makes code clean and avoid future bugs (but that's out of this story :-)

Comment: ((Confusing however is that the assigned lambda expression seems to run faster than the others, even than the C-one.)):
The problem is probably the concurrency. I don't exactly know what happens, but when you run the threads one-at-a-time I get a result like this:

1954073390 bare function pointer
1952530828 C++11 function object to bare function
1953096356 C++11 function object to object method
1953336344 C++11 function object to object method (virtual)
1951464452 C++11 function object to lambda expression 10-th second.
All very closely together.

Comment: @trapni: (I know this is old, and may be irrelevant.) There is a potentially *huge* performance problem in "**false sharing**" of all the counters. Try placing them apart from each other (each on their own cache line) and see whether you get a significant performance improvement or not.

Comment: @yzt sorry, I just found your response this moment (merry christmas!), did you actually try out yourself of what you're proposing? But yes, I believe that it's about the CPU caches that make all as fast as the others. But in *real* apps you're having more bulk code around your actual function calls, which might render into different results then. I'd be highly interested in a more in-depth analysis on this matter, too.

Comment: @trapni: I did check this a few months back when I commented here. What I remember is that the performance was improved, after I fixed a few other things in the benchmark as well (I don't remember what; I *might* be able to dig up the code.)

Comment: @trapni: To solve the problem of "false sharing" between threads (which I have to emphasize has nothing to do with what this program is trying to benchmark, since this does *not* need to be a multi-threaded program,) you just have to insert some padding between the **counters**. It has nothing to do with the code. Just make sure the counters are at least 64 bytes (one cacheline worth) apart in memory.

Answer (score 9):

`std::function` performs type erasure on the function type and there is more than one way to implement it, so you maybe should add which version of which compiler you are using to get an exact answer.

`boost::function` is largely identical to a `std::function` and comes with an [FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/function/faq.html#id1617612) entry on call overhead and some [general section on performance](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/function/misc.html#id1617757). Those give some hints on how a function object performs. If this applies in your case, depends on your implementation but numbers shouldn't be significantly different.

Comment: Btw, the FAQ says: "The cost of boost::function can be reasonably consistently measured at around 20ns +/- 10 ns on a modern >2GHz platform versus directly inlining the code.". That's not a great statement IMO. It does not give *relative* estimates and does not compare it to non-virtual function calls (only to inlining)

Comment: @AndyProwl Yes, but such statements are incredibly hard to make and the benchmarks are really hard to write and usually also compiler version dependent. It is better than no statement at all.

Comment: I believe the Boost people would be happy about some benchmark code submitted as patch, so people can measure the actual impact on their particular platform.

Comment: @balki If what is theoretical possible? To write a benchmark? Certainly, but it is tricky. I depends what you care about: size, call speed, speed of copy/moves?

Answer (score 7):

I run a quick benchmark using  [**Google Benchmark**](https://github.com/google/benchmark)
Those are the results:

```
Run on (4 X 2712 MHz CPU s)
----------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                   Time           CPU Iterations
----------------------------------------------------------
RawFunctionPointer         11 ns         11 ns   56000000
StdBind                    12 ns         12 ns   64000000
StdFunction                11 ns         11 ns   56000000
Lambda                      9 ns          9 ns   64000000
```

It seems that the most optimal solution is using lambdas (just like user *christianparpart* mentioned in this thread). The code I used for benchmark can be found below.

```
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

static volatile int global_var = 0;

void my_int_func(int x)
{
    global_var = x + x + 3;
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(global_var);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(x);
}

static void RawFunctionPointer(benchmark::State &state)
{
    void (*bar)(int) = &my_int_func;
    srand (time(nullptr));
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        bar(rand());
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(my_int_func);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(bar);
    }
}

static void StdFunction(benchmark::State &state)
{
    std::function<void(int)> bar = my_int_func;
    srand (time(nullptr));
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        bar(rand());
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(my_int_func);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(bar);
    }
}

static void StdBind(benchmark::State &state)
{
    auto bar = std::bind(my_int_func, std::placeholders::_1);
    srand (time(nullptr));
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        bar(rand());
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(my_int_func);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(bar);
    }
}

static void Lambda(benchmark::State &state)
{
    auto bar = [](int x) {
        global_var = x + x + 3;
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(global_var);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(x);
    };
    srand (time(nullptr));
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        bar(rand());
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(my_int_func);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(bar);
    }
}


BENCHMARK(RawFunctionPointer);
BENCHMARK(StdBind);
BENCHMARK(StdFunction);
BENCHMARK(Lambda);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

Comment: Glad to see this, but I will suggest that remove `rand` in the test for a loop since it's very slow and will cost much of the run time.

Comment: It's been used in every benchmark function as an argument for the function. Why do you consider the rand() to disturb the benchmark results?

Comment: @KamilKuczaj it's a function that does by no means guarantee constant time, and it's varying by far more than the overhead. Also, you're "DoNotOptimize" a lot of things, most of which you really shouldn't if you want to benchmark invocation. Also, it's useless to the benchmark?

Comment: Replacing `rand` by a simple `rng_state = (rng_state << 13) ^ 0xDEADCAFE; bar(rng_state);` results in overall execution that is two to three times faster than with `rand`. So, your benchmark is almost certainly dominated by the overhead that calling `rand()` in that context had. (which very much might be a question of efficient use of stack!)

Comment: https://quick-bench.com/q/EgY8KtLhv6MnWYkArIOCtfTFI8U