# Linking two function pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

I have a vector of function pointers (`void (*)()`) representing a list of actions you have already taken.  How could I pop out the last two and make it into one function pointer and put it back in the list?

Example:

```
void link_last_two(std::vector<void (*)()> actions) {
    if(actions.size() <= 1) return;
    void (*first)() = actions.back();
    actions.pop_back();
    void (*second)() = actions.back();
    actions.push_back([](){first(); second();});
}
```

Comment: Use `std::function` instead of raw function pointers.

Comment: You can do it using a hackish solution. If you have control over the code, use `std::function` instead, as suggested also by @BasileStarynkevitch.

Comment: A function pointer is just a pointer - an address in memory where the machine code of a function is located. "first" points to some address, "second" points to some address; which address do you want the new function to point? There's no existing function to point to, and you probably are not asking about generating machine code for a fresh new function and pointing to that. That's why you should use something else for describing functions rather than pointers. std::function is a great choice.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Isn't that INCREDIBLY SLOW?  I can change the source (I haven't coded it yet)

Comment: I doubt there is any way to accomplish what you want. You cannot dynamically synthesize a static function, and get a pointer to it.

Comment: If you want to be able to combine two actions into one, then you should not have a vector of fctn ptrs, but a `vector<SomethingThatPossibilyRepresentAListOfActions>`. Shouldn't be hard to implement such a class, and could be fun.

Comment: @Czipperz, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306497/performance-of-stdfunction-compared-to-raw-function-pointer-and-void-this

Answer (score 0):

With `void(*)()`, you can't. This is simply a consequence of the fact that there is no context whatsoever. You can create a function `void helper()` and store a pointer to that, but how would `helper` know which two functions to call?

As noted, `std::function<void(void)>` does have the required context. Alternatively, store a list of

```
std::pair<void*, union {
   void(*)(void) no_context;
   void(*)(void*) context;
  }>
```

If the first `void*` is `nullptr`, call the `no_context` function, else call the `context` function passing the non-null `void*` pointer.