# Select object for call function at run time, without base class and templates

Tags: c++

I have two classes with same interface methods:

```
struct ImplGenerated {
    int foo(int x, int y);
    void bar(double x);
    ....
};

struct ImplCustom {
    int foo(int x, int y);
    void bar(double x);
    .....
};
```

And class Wrapper:

```
struct Wrapper {
    Wrapper(ImplGenerated * i): m_generated(i), m_custom(0) {}
    Wrapper(ImplCustom * i): m_generated(0), m_custom(i) {}
    int foo(int x, int y);
    void bar(double x);
    ....
private:
    ??? getImpl();
    ImplGenerated * m_generated;
    ImplCustom * m_custom;
};

int Wrapper::foo(int x, int y) {
    return getImpl()->foo(x, y);
}
void Wrapper::bar(double x) {
    getImpl()->bar(x);
}
```

Is it possible to write some C++ construction (class or any other, but not macros) instead **getImpl()** for resolving current implementation object and call corresponding method?
like this:

```
???? getImpl() {
    return m_custom ? m_custom : m_generated;
}
```

Note:
Only changes to ImplCustom could be applied (add base class or make template or something else), ImplGenerated is auto-generated by external project therefore couldn't be changed (**add base class is impossible**).
Wrapper could not be template, because is interface class.

Update:
It is impossible to derive ImplCustom from ImplGenerated.

Comment: Is it possible to derive `ImplCustom` from `ImplGenerated`?

Comment: You just cannot change a function's return type at runtime. The options are runtime polymorphism - base class pointer/reference and virtual functions, or compile time polymorhism - templates to generate more than one function.

Answer (score 4):

The solution I see here is to create a wrapper

The goal of this solution is to generate an interface for your two unrelated classes.

Let's start by making a Base classe:

```
struct ImplInterface {
    virtual int foo(int x, int y) = 0;
    virtual void bar(double x) = 0;
    // ...
};
```

Now you can create wrapper for each Impl you got:

```
struct GeneratedWrapper : ImplInterface {
    virtual int foo(int x, int y) {
        _impl.foo(x, y);
    }

    virtual void bar(double x) {
        _impl.bar(x);
    }

private:
    ImplGenerated _impl;
};

struct CustomWrapper : ImplInterface {
    virtual int foo(int x, int y) {
        _impl.foo(x, y);
    }

    virtual void bar(double x) {
        _impl.bar(x);
    }

private:
    ImplCustom _impl;
};
```

Now you can use these wrapper like this:

```
ImplInterface* wrapper = new GeneratedWrapper(implGenerated);
```

This method could be much shorter using templates, let's make One wrapper for your new interface:

```
template<typename T>
struct EveryImplWrapper : ImplInterface {
    virtual int foo(int x, int y) {
        _impl.foo(x, y);
    }

    virtual void bar(double x) {
        _impl.bar(x);
    }

private:
    T _impl;
};
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
ImplInterface* = new EveryImplWrapper<ImplCustom>(implCustom);
```

Comment: Interesting idea! Thanks! You made me think about how it can be applied to my project.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't modify the existing classes, you can still add a facade to provide post-hoc polymorphism. That is:

> Wrapper could not be template, because is interface class

is  only partly true. You can have a non-templated interface (ABC) and a templated concrete subclass.

```
// publically visible parts
struct ImplInterface {
    virtual ~ImplInterface() {}
    virtual int foo(int x, int y) = 0;
    virtual void bar(double x) = 0;
    ....
};

struct Wrapper {
    // ...
    ImplInterface *Wrapper::getImpl();
    // ... do you want to keep the same impl selection across calls?
    ImplInterface *m_impl;
};

// implementation details can be hidden in a cpp file

template <typename RealImpl>
struct ImplFacade: ImplInterface {
    RealImpl pimpl_;

    explicit ImplFacade(RealImpl *impl) : pimpl_(impl) {}

    int foo(int x, int y) override { return pimpl_->foo(x,y); }
    void bar(double x)    override { pimpl_->bar(x); }
};

ImplInterface *Wrapper::getImpl() {
    if (!m_impl) {
        if (m_custom)
            m_impl = new ImplFacade<ImplCustom>(m_custom);
        else
            m_impl = new ImplFacade<ImplGenerated>(m_generated);
    }
    return m_impl;
}
```

Ideally you should be using `unique_ptr` for the new member in real code.

Comment: It is ideal solution, but is very hard to realize in current project, with hundreds methods and interfaces

Comment: If you have hundreds of methods and interfaces, _nothing_ is going to be easy, unless you can find a way to generate the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the c++11 Standard you can use `std::function` to accomplish this:

```
struct Wrapper {
    Wrapper(ImplGenerated * i):
        foo(std::bind(&ImplGenerated::foo, i)),
        bar(std::bind(&ImplGenerated::bar, i)) {}

    Wrapper(ImplCustom * i):
        foo(std::bind(&ImplCustom ::foo, i)),
        bar(std::bind(&ImplCustom ::bar, i)) {}

    //Now the functions are member variables but it works the same way
    std::function<int(int x, int y)> foo;
    std::function<void(double x)> bar;
    ....

//If you don't Need to destruct the impl-objects then you don't even Need to store them
};
```

Comment: This would imply a lot of dynamic allocation and a lot of indirection :(

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot actually, `std::function` have a very good Performance. I also think that the won't be much dynamic allocation since it's just binding one member function.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Yes, I can use c++11 Standard. This decision imply to write a lot of code, but I would like to do the writing less code

Comment: @EvgenyKlyuzin You're welcome! Actually if you look closer you can see that you don't Need to write so much code because you don't Need to write the implementation of the functions... You just bind them in the constructor

Comment: @Thomas Sparber Maybe! It would be interesting to see what are the performance of `std::function` vs virtual dispatch.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Well you can see that :-) See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306497/performance-of-stdfunction-compared-to-raw-function-pointer-and-void-this

Comment: @Thomas Sparber Thanks for link!

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you're wanting is to use inheritance / interface:

```
struct ImplInterface {
    virtual int foo(int x, int y) = 0;
    virtual void bar(double x) = 0;
    ....
};

struct ImplGenerated : public ImplInterface {
    virtual int foo(int x, int y);
    virtual void bar(double x);
    ....
};

struct ImplCustom : public ImplInterface {
    virtual int foo(int x, int y);
    virtual void bar(double x);
    .....
};
```

now your `getImpl()` will return a `ImplInterface*`

Or if you can't add a base class, then in your `Wrapper` class instead of `getImpl()` do this:

```
int foo(int x, int y)
{
    if (m_generated != nullptr)
    {
         return m_generated->foo(x,y);
    }
    else if (m_custom != nullptr)
    {
         return m_custom->foo(x, y);
    }
    throw "hey dude!";
}
```

I know it's a lot of work, but hey you've no base class to work with.

Comment: Thanks for an answer! But i couldn't add base class for ImplGenerated

Comment: @EvgenyKlyuzin, see my edit.  The other option, if the `ImplGenerated` class's methods are `virtual` you could derive `ImplCustom` from `ImplGenerated` and override the methods.

Comment: This solution currently applied in my project. Lots of bloated code for every interface method. That is actual problem. I have hundreds of methods with same logic. Hard to maintain, write tests and keep in mind during developing.

Comment: @EvgenyKlyuzin, maybe Guillaume Racicot's answer is the one to use if inheritance from `ImplGenerated` is not possible.

Comment: I will not -1 your answer because it could work, but it does not solve the actual problem.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, maybe not, but it does resolve the way the question was worded. Even the OP said so. Thanks for the condescension.

Comment: I make his question work indeed, but it does not solve the "Lots of bloated code for every interface method. That is actual problem."

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, You are correct that it doesn't solve the 'Lots of bloated code', but that requirement came **after** my post and even **after** my edit. I think the best solution is yours, but the `std::function` one is intriguing, too.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz oh ok then, sorry. Yes, I didn't thought about std function here.

Comment: Hey, why the downvote? It answered the question as originally posed. Sheesh.