# Does std::tuple accept auto as a type

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, stdtuple

I have to return an int and a function object to the caller, I was thought of returning a tuple like `make_tuple(int,[](some){})` I am now on GCC that doesn't support `decltpe(auto)` as a return type, is ther any way i could make my return type as `std::tuple<int,auto> myfun()` right now I've been doing like below(but not sure)

```
auto myfun()->decltype(make_tuple(100,p))
{
   auto p=[](some){};
   return make_tuple(100,p);
}
```

what I am doing is ok?

Comment: Does this compile?  It shouldn't.

Comment: Why do you need `decltype(auto)` here? If your compiler supports return type deduction for functions, then getting rid of the trailing return type in the example above should work.

Comment: So it's quicker to ask a question here than create a simple testcase and try compiling that?

Comment: @FallingFromBed You can always create a [mcve] and compile that to test things.  That would have told you it would not compile.

Comment: @FallingFromBed what cpu do you have? Compiling this on my computer takes a fraction of a second. Hardly unbearable.

Comment: "I am now on GCC that doesn't support `decltpe(auto)` [sic] as a return type" False. It does. Did you downgrade to some ancient version? Anyway, that's not why this code can't compile, as simple testing would've shown. One need not ask "scholars" to predict what a 4-line program will do.

Comment: Best practice is to make an effort on your own before demanding help. If it's not previously answered, do a self-answering Q&A afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, since `p` is not available at that scope, and a lambda expression shall not appear in unevaluated context (which is decltype). (See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232164/why-are-lambda-expressions-not-allowed-in-an-unevaluated-operands-but-allowed-in))

You can, however, wrap it in an `std::function`:

```
std::tuple<int, std::function<void(some)>> myfun()
{
  std::function<void(some)> p = [](some){};
  return std::forward_as_tuple(100, p);
}
```

Comment: `std::funciton` adds indirection where none is originally required. I do not like this.

Comment: @SergeyA You cannot return a type that you don't know.  I can't see a better way without putting the type outside the function.

Comment: same remark as from @SergeyA. If there are no variables captured, I'd use a function pointer instead of std::function (--no indirection through type erasure)... or better avoid the problem and define `p` outside of the function.

Comment: @davidhigh: A function pointer is just as bad as `std::function` (no inlining possible). If performance is really that critical, the callable type should be defined outside the function.

Comment: @NathanOliver, neitheir do I - or I'd provide one in the answer. I still can dislike this one, can't i?

Comment: @SergeyA Sure you can.  I think I overreacted and interpreted disliked as down vote which is not the case.  I'll go back to pondering a solution.

Comment: @erenon: I meant I'd use it if I really need it hard and dirty :-). In this case, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306497/performance-of-stdfunction-compared-to-raw-function-pointer-and-void-this), for example, for some not too definite answers