# virtual method callbacks in C++11/14/17?

Tags: c++11, c++14, c++17, std-function, stdbind

I have some subscription function that will call my callback when something happens.  (Let's say it's a timer, and will pass me an object when a certain number of milliseconds elapses.)  The thing I want to be called is a virtual method.  I feel `std::function` and `std::bind` or lambdas are part of the solution.

The C++99 approach I've used until now involves one-line C functions that know how to call a virtual method.  The subscription function takes the C function and a void* user data as arguments.  For example:

```
class Foo {
  virtual void OnTimerA( Data* pd );
};

void OnTimerACB( Data* pd, void* pvUserData ) {
  ( (Foo*) pvUserData )->OnTimerA( pd );
}

/* Inside some method of Foo; 1000 is a number of milliseconds to call me back in;
   second arg is a function pointer; third is a void* user data that is passed back
   to the C callback. */
SubscribeToTimerOld( 1000, OnTimerACB, this );
```

What I'm hoping for is a way to write:

```
SubscribeToTimerNew( 1000, OnTimerA );
```

or something similar, at least that disposes of the need to write that one-line C binding callback.

I have a feeling that `SubscribeToTimerNew()`'s argument is probably a `std:function` of some sort and instead of merely writing `OnTimerA` I'd have to write something with `std::bind` to get the `this` pointer in there.

Alternatively to `bind`, perhaps a lambda is the way to do it?  This compiles, though I dont see how to extend it to let the event handler pass an argument to `OnTimerA()`.  (My linker isn't currently working so don't know if it links or runs as desired.)

```
SubscribeTimer(  1000, [this](){this->OnTimerA();} );
```

To mention one alternative I've discarded: give `Foo` a superclass with a method called `OnTimer()` that will be called when the timer goes off.  Now `SubscribeTimer()` only need take an elapsed time.  I don't like this as it doesn't cleanly allow for multiple timers to be registered.  If it did you could give them (say) integer timer ID's and implement `OnTimer()` as a `switch` but this seems to be a lot more complicated than the C++99 solution.

Ultimately of the (I assume) several approaches, are there any trade-offs (e.g., heap use) in addition the most obvious question of how much typing is involved?  (This is a high-performance application and I'd prefer to minimize or eliminate heap usage.)

Comment: Have a read about performance comparison: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306497/performance-of-stdfunction-compared-to-raw-function-pointer-and-void-this tldr quote from accepted answer: "a C++11's std::function call just adds 2 more CPU instructions, thus 5 in our example. As a conclusion: it absolutely doesn't matter what way of function pointer technique you use, the overhead differences are in any case very small."

Answer (score 0):

C++11, C++14 and C++17 are quite different, especially when it comes to lambdas. And lambdas are a great way to create callbacks. For instance, see [Why use std::bind over lambdas in C++14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363003/why-use-stdbind-over-lambdas-in-c14)

Using modern C++, you can use `std::function` as your callback type and then you can use any callable stuff as an actual callback. Quote from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function:

> Class template `std::function` is a general-purpose polymorphic function
>   wrapper. Instances of `std::function` can store, copy, and invoke any
>   *Callable* target -- functions, lambda expressions, bind expressions, or
>   other function objects, as well as pointers to member functions and
>   pointers to data members.

Example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using Callback = std::function<void(int)>;

void subscribe(Callback callback, int duration) {
    callback(duration);
}

struct Foo {
    void operator()(int duration) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ' ' << duration << '\n';
    }
};

struct Bar {
    virtual void myFunction(int duration) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ' ' << duration << '\n';
    }
};

void freeFunction(int duration) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ' ' << duration << '\n';
}


struct Zorg {
    static void staticFunction(int duration) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ' ' << duration << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    subscribe(foo, 128);

    Bar bar;
    auto lambda = [&bar](int duration) {
        bar.myFunction(duration);
    };
    subscribe(lambda, 256);

    subscribe(freeFunction, 512);

    subscribe(Zorg::staticFunction, 1024);
}
```

Output:

> void Foo::operator()(int) 128
>
> virtual void Bar::myFunction(int) 256
>
> void freeFunction(int) 512
>
> static void Zorg::staticFunction(int) 1024

Comment: You could improve your answer by implementing actual subscription, not just invoking passed `std::function` in `subscribe`. It would be show case that `std::function` can be stored for later use, what is the purpose of callbacks.