# C++ function pointer callback

Tags: c++, pointers, callback, pointer-to-member

I want to be able to pass a function from a class called `Game` inside of a namespace called `Application` to another function inside a class called `Button` inside the namespace `Engine` however I'm unsure how to do it and how to call the function.

Background information, the Game class has an entity that, when clicked I want to call a function that is stored in the Button component.

`Game.h`

```
namespace Application
{
    class Game
    {
        void Print(Engine::ButtonData data)
        {
            if (data.buttonPressed == Engine::MouseButton::Left)
                std::cout << "Left\n";
            else if (data.buttonPressed == Engine::MouseButton::Right)
                std::cout << "Right\n";
        }

        e1->button = new Engine::Component::Button(Print); // This is just where the function is passed to the button class for storage
    };
}
```

`Button.h` - Only data is to be stored in this class

```
namespace Engine
{
    namespace Component
    {
        class Button
        {
        public:
            Button() {}
            
            Button(void(* callback)(ButtonData))
                : m_Callback(callback)
            {}

            void(* m_Callback)(ButtonData);
        };
    }
}
```

`Entity Manager` - Where the function needs to be called

```
comp->m_Callback(ButtonData(
                        Mouse::GetCurrentButton(),
                        std::pair<int, int>(Mouse::GetMouseX(), Mouse::GetMouseY()),
                        comp->m_Callback)
                    );
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] demonstrating what you intend to do.

Comment: I usually use std::functions nowadays because of their flexibility : Some ideas here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306497/performance-of-stdfunction-compared-to-raw-function-pointer-and-void-this

Comment: @user17732522 I've added some code snippets, however I don't see the relevancy as I'm asking how to do something now how to fix something that is broken

Comment: @CallumS Without some code it is not clear what exactly you want to do. For example, still, it is not clear to me on what `Game` instance you want the function to be called. Is `e1->button` supposed to be a non-static member of `Game` and is the function supposed to be called on the `Game` object containing that `Button` object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Callback functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298242/callback-functions-in-c)